# Cakephp3 Saving Multiple dropdown selections to database

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a form with a dropdown that is multiple => true

```
echo $this - > Form - > input('test_id', [
  'options' => $tests,
  'required' => true,
  'empty' => 'Select Tests',
  'multiple' => true
]);
```

But when i submit the form only one value is saved in database. 
I have searched for solution and found this:
[Multiple select in input Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314273/multiple-select-in-input-cakephp)

It suggests using **[SaveMany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)** in my Controller, but i can't figure it out how to use it to get my desired output.

I'm very new to this framework so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried debug() in your controller to see if all of the selected IDS are being submitted correctly

Answer (score 0):

sorry i m also new but as other answers and question i don't see `'selected' => $selected` in your form

[CakePHP 2.0 Select form Mulitple selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492031/cakephp-2-0-select-form-mulitple-selected)
and [How to set selection in mulitiselect list box in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576717/how-to-set-selection-in-mulitiselect-list-box-in-cakephp)

Comment: I think you havnt got my question, I want to ask how to add all the selected values to the database, may in this form: "test1, test2, test3"